# CiviCRM permissions get wiped out after each upgrade (except for Public and Super Admin user groups)

Tags: joomla, permissions, acl

Is anyone experiencing an issue where all CiviCRM permissions in Joomla get completely reset (meaning all permissions items are set to "Inherit") after every CiviCRM upgrade? Only the Public and Super Admin user groups' CiviCRM permissions remain the same as before the upgrade.

Last time I saw this happen was just yesterday after upgrading to CiviCRM 5.10.4 on Joomla 3.9.3. Have observed this for a few months now, and decided I was tired of manually re-doing all permissions after each upgrade : (

Comment: Yes, I experience the same on Drupal. Our ACL settings just doesn't work after the CiviCRM upgrade. :-(

Comment: Thanks, Karel. I'm surprised we're not hearing more of this ... one would think this is a pretty impactful issue. If moderators see this, please suggest how you want us to confirm this (simply using the demo site won't do here). I'm happy to create a clean install of Joomla + Civi; others may be willing to do the same for Drupal (heck, I may do so, as well, if it would mean I can log a bug).